# Python 3.4 - pyodbc character set / formatting issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

Having problems with the following code.  It basically is doing a "show table", replacing a string and executing output string.

The table definition

```
from macpath import join
import pyodbc
from builtins import print
import logging
import re
import codecs

#pyodbc connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver=Teradata;DBCName=192.168.1.103;DATABASE=testdb;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx')

#create cursor
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("""
    show table ENVIRON1.DEPT
    """)
except pyodbc.Error as err:
    logging.warning(err)

objectlist = cursor.fetchall()
for row in objectlist:
            our_str = str(objectlist[0])
            our_str = re.sub("ENVIRON1", "ENVIRON2", our_str, flags=re.I)
            print(our_str)
            try:
               cursor.execute(our_str)
            except pyodbc.Error as err:
                logging.warning(err) 
            except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as err:
                logging.warning(err)
```

The table definition is as follows:

```
CREATE SET TABLE ENVIRON1.DEPT ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT
     (
      Key_Id SMALLINT NOT NULL
  )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( Key_Id  );
```

The output of 
    print(ourstr)
is

```
('CREATE SET TABLE ENVIRON2.DEPT ,NO FALLBACK ,\r     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,\r     NO AFTER JOURNAL,\r     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,\r     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO\r     (\r      Key_Id SMALLINT NOT NULL)\rUNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( Key_Id );', )
```

The output of

```
cursor.execute(our_str)
```

is

```
 WARNING:root:('42000', "[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error, expected something like a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' or a 'NONTEMPORAL' keyword or 'AS' keyword between '(' and the string 'CREATE SET TABLE ENVIRON2.DEPT ,NO FALLBACK ,\\r     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,\\r     NO AFTER JOURNAL,\\r     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT.  (-3707) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

THe problem is with the carriage return \r.  The   cursor.execute(our_str) statement is taking the carriage return as a literal "\r" causing a syntax error

Any tips on how i can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```python
our_str = str(objectlist[0])
```

you are converting an entire "row" to a string (even though that row may contain only one column), so the string comes out as

```
('line1\rline2',)
```

If you extract the *first column* from the row then you should just get the undecorated string

```python
our_str = objectlist[0][0]
```

which when printed should look like

```
line1
line2
```

Or, instead of `fetchall()` you could just do `fetchone()` since it looks like you only expect to retrieve one row anyway. In that case

```python
our_str = objectlist[0]
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thanks Gord.  Worked perfectly :-)